# Apply permutation test after nested cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, permutation

I ran a **nested**-cross validation procedure on my data set. Now I would like to assess the significance of the average performance of all outer models. Is there any package that allows me to do this? I came across [`sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.permutation_test_score.html#sklearn-model-selection-permutation-test-score) but it seems that this function only takes one classifier as input and I also don't know how I would have to implement this function for my problem. I am looking for a way to assess the significance of the average classification performance of all surrogate models that are returned by `cross_validate`.

Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get iris data set
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# set random seed
random_seed = 42

# use support vector machine
svr = SVC()

# optimize C-Parameter
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10, 100]}

# Define cross-validation strategies
inner_cv = KFold(shuffle=True,random_state=random_seed)
outer_cv = KFold(shuffle=True,random_state=random_seed)

# define inner cv
grid = GridSearchCV(svr,param_grid=p_grid,cv=inner_cv)

# define outer cv
scores = cross_validate(grid,X,y,cv=outer_cv,return_train_score=True,return_estimator=True)

# get average performance across all surrogate models
avg_test_score = np.mean(scores['test_score'])

# plot results
x = np.arange(len(scores['estimator']))
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
train_scores = ax.bar(x - width/2,height=scores['train_score'],width=width,label='Train Score')
test_scores = ax.bar(x + width/2,height=scores['test_score'],width=width,label='Test Score')
ax.axhline(y=avg_test_score, xmin=0.0, xmax=1.0, color='orange')
ax.set_ylabel('Score')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(['Outer Fold 1','Outer Fold 2','Outer Fold 3','Outer Fold 4','Outer Fold 5'])
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),loc='center left')
```

In this example the average performance across all five surrogate models is `avg_test_score≈0.97`. Now is there a way to assess the significance of this average value by repeating the whole procedure *n* times, shuffling the labels, and obtain the frequency of this value or a higher one?

times

[image]